# Get OpenStreetMap data for USA state boundaries using R osmdata package

Tags: r, openstreetmap

I'd like to download data for California (i.e., parking lots > 8100 m2). But I can't get osmdata::getbb() to produce the correct boundary.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(osmdata)
library(sf)
library(mapview)

osm_data<- getbb ("california",
                    display_name_contains="United States",
                    format_out = "polygon") %>%
  opq() %>%
  add_osm_feature("amenity","parking")%>%
  osmdata_sf()


PL<-osm_data$osm_polygons%>%mutate(area=st_area(.))%>%filter(as.numeric(area)>8100)

mapview(PL)
```

It returns polygons for the Oakland area only. Does someone know how to get the correct bbox for California?

Comment: Consider gadm.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `getbb` query returns polygons for six things that match "california". Four of them clearly have coordinates far from the state, which has a longitude around -122:

```
> cabb = getbb("California", display_name_contains="United States", format="polygon")
> str(cabb)
List of 6
 $ : num [1:1307, 1:2] -122 -122 -122 -122 -122 ...
 $ : num [1:212, 1:2] -92.6 -92.6 -92.6 -92.6 -92.6 ...
 $ : num [1:8, 1:2] -92.6 -92.6 -92.6 -92.6 -92.6 ...
 $ : num [1:10, 1:2] -84.3 -84.3 -84.3 -84.3 -84.3 ...
 $ : num [1:453, 1:2] -79.9 -79.9 -79.9 -79.9 -79.9 ...
 $ :List of 8
  ..$ : num [1:7901, 1:2] -124 -124 -124 -124 -124 ...
  ..$ : num [1:100, 1:2] -123 -123 -123 -123 -123 ...
  ..$ : num [1:394, 1:2] -121 -121 -121 -121 -121 ...
  ..$ : num [1:48, 1:2] -120 -120 -120 -120 -120 ...
  ..$ : num [1:121, 1:2] -120 -120 -120 -120 -120 ...
  ..$ : num [1:74, 1:2] -119 -119 -119 -119 -119 ...
  ..$ : num [1:191, 1:2] -119 -119 -119 -119 -119 ...
  ..$ : num [1:140, 1:2] -119 -119 -119 -119 -119 ...
```

The sixth element here is a multipolygon which looks most like the state, so you can get the mainland boundary which is the first element of that.

```
> bb = cabb[[6]][[1]]
```

However I now think you will hit timeout and size problems because California has a *lot* of parking amenties...

```
> osm_data = bb %>% opq() %>% add_osm_feature("amenity","parking") %>% osmdata_sf()
Error in check_for_error(doc) : General overpass server error; returned:
The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL. runtime error: Query timed out in "query" at line 4 after 26 seconds. 
>
```

I'd suggest you get the latest extract from GeoFabrik (https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/california.html) and work on that instead if you hit limits of the OSM search.

Comment: Correct on all accounts -- thank you! I appreciate the link for the shp file download of N and S CA too. I thought I could only download the osm.pbf for CA and was having trouble extracting the data.